# Are keywords, operators, etc stored in memory like objects?

Tags: python, object, memory, operators, keyword

I am trying to make a conceptual distinction between Python objects and other language elements such as keywords (e.g. `return` and `def`) and operators (e.g. `+` and `-`) memory-wise. I know that objects are stored in memory and they have a memory id and a size. The id and size can be found out with `id(object)` and `sys.getsizeof(object)` respectively.

Are non-objects such as keywords and operators also stored in memory? If yes, are they stored in the same way as objects or different? Do `return` and `def` have a slot like string "Foo" and text 10 have?

Answer (score 1):

They are not as that would be a big waste of memory. I am not sure about scripting languages, but normally the compiler creates the binary codes for operators or keywords. Then they are loaded into the memory when you run the application.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a compiled language; the Python source you are used to looking at is compiled to an assembly-like byte code which is actually executed.

For example:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 1
```

becomes

```
>>> type(foo)
<class 'function'>
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `def` keyword itself isn't represented; rather, it causes a `function` object to be created. This object has a `__code__` attribute which consists of the sequence of byte code shown above. Likewise, the `return` keyword causes a `RETURN_VALUE` operation to be generated.